# What does (z) mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In complex analysis, if *z* is complex number, what does (*z*) mean?
The symbol is a mathematical fraktur capital J, unicode U+1D50D.

Comment: Imaginary part of $z$

Answer (score 3):

Other notations for ${\rm Re}(z)$ and ${\rm Im}(z)$ are ${\frak R}(z)$ and ${\frak I}(z)$. This ${\frak I}$ looks like a "J" but it is actually an "I" in fraktur font: `\frak I`. The "J" in fraktur font, $\frak J$ is very similar to "I" and I believe that is also used for ${\rm Im}(z)$. If this isn't the case, the only reasonable alternative would be to guess that ${\frak J}(z)$ denotes rotation of $z$ by $90^\circ$, since in linear algebra we usually denote a complex structure by $J$ (although uncecessary).

Comment: `\Im` in LaTeX gives $\Im$, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Im z = \operatorname{Im} z $$